# How can I change the color of my dropdown inside a list on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this list inside my webpage, but I need to color my dropdown red when I hover it, and keep it red when I am inside the dropdown list.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 113px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.129412) 0px 2px 4px 0px;
}
    
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
    
.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #d60041;
}
    
.dropdown-content a {
    text-align: left;
}
    
.dropdown-link {
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    
 .dropdown-link:hover .drop {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="textnavbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="myBtn">Il mio account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <ul>
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="textnavbar"><a href="#">Prime</a></li>
    <li class="textnavbar"><a href="#">Carrello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you already tried something with JS?

Comment: so I need to put <li> and </li>?

Comment: Arkej I did but I couldn't find the solution

Comment: $('#myBtn').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("border","0");
I did something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

li:hover div > a {
  background-color: #d60041;
}
```

The `>` stands for `direct descendent of the parent element`
If you remove it, all `a` links will get an `background-color` on hover.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 113px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.129412) 0px 2px 4px 0px;
}

li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

li:hover div > a {
  background-color: #d60041;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #d60041;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-link {
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown-link:hover .drop {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="textnavbar">
     <div class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" id="myBtn">Il mio account</a>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
          <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="textnavbar"><a href="#">Prime</a></li>
<li class="textnavbar"><a href="#">Carrello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your right, i coudnt find a better word ;) Ill update it with ur word.